# Redis and Relationship

Tags: redis, associations

I'm planning to use a caching layer for my application. I'm not sure what is the right strategy for defining 1..N and self-referential relationships.

For instance, if I have to represent Course and Students, a course can have 1..N students enrolled. I also have to maintain a relationship between different courses that are related to each other (a course can be linked to other similar courses).

I think I have 2 options:

1. I can have a model of Course that has a list of student ids and related course ids. I have now store the Course as a hash in redis. Whenever a student is added to the list, I can get the course from cache, make changes and put it back on cache.
2. I can model the course that just has the basic attributes of the course. I can now represent the relationship with students and other course using Redis list.

Which is a better approach? and Why?.

If a course is removed, I have to remove all the associated relationships. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Redis is a a **non-relational** key-value store.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to re-think your solution if you're going to use Redis. Avoid thinking about relationship like in a relational database.

In Redis, you might both store complete objects as JSON or any other serialization format, and also in data structures like lists, sets, sorted sets and hashes.

The whole associations won't be enforced by Redis but by your application layer, but I'm going to suggest you that, again, you should re-think how you're going to store data in Redis.

For example, if you've courses and students, you may store both in redis in a unrelated way:

- learningcenter:course:123
- learningcenter:student:1129

And if you need to add students to a given course, you would create a key of *set* type:

- learningcenter:course:123:students

...where you would store student unique identifiers, for example:

```
sadd learningcenter:course:123:students 1129
```

At the end of the day, `course` has N `students`, but this wouldn't be well represented in Redis: it's how your code stores data in the whole Redis database.

The key point is having such sets of unique identifiers in order to ensure you're spreading them across your database without the risk of adding unexisting references to some data.

When you need to add a new student and associate it to one or multiple courses, you'll need to do the whole `sadd` commands yourself, and when you want to remove a student, you'll need to be sure that you remove its key and from any set.

### Redis supports transactions

[You should take a look at how Redis handles transactions,](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) because you'll need to perform such write operations atomically in order to avoid data corruption.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I got the idea.

Comment: @user3261334 No problem! That's why we're here at SO